# Adding a listener to hyperlink in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, hyperlink

I simply want to add a hyper link in my application. I tried the following code and the link is appearing in the page. But the on click event is not working. Can anyone please tell me what might be the reason?

```
xtype:'box',
isFormField: true,
id: "prospectStageLink",
style: "padding: 3px",
autoEl:{
    //html: '&nbsp;<a href>Link To Prospect</a>'
    tag: 'a',
    href: '#',
    cn: 'Link To Prospect'
},
listeners: {
    render: function(c){
        c.on('click', function(e){
            alert('clicked', 'hiii');
        }, c, { stopEvent: true });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
listeners: {
    render: function(component) {
        component.getEl().on('click', function(e) {
            alert('test');
        });    
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked. but when i call a function inside the click event function it doesn't work.why?

Comment: what function are you trying to call? check out the scope of your function

Comment: function defined in that javascript only..outside the panel in which hyperlink is defined.

Comment: Oh i forgot the order in which the functions are defined matters. That was the problem with my code.Thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not running on ExtJS 4, because BoxComponent was removed from it.

Anyways, the simple explanation is probably that [BoxComponent](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.BoxComponent) does not have a `click` event. You might want to try using an [Element](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Element) instead, which does have support for the `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
xtype:'box',
isFormField: true,
id: "prospectStageLink",
style: "padding: 3px",
autoEl:{
    //html: '&nbsp;<a href>Link To Prospect</a>'
    tag: 'a',
    href: '',
    onClick: 'nameYouFunction'
}
```